# Update array of objects depending on other array of object value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have two arrays of objects and I want to update one depending on other's propery value.

If `driveTypeArray.multiAssign` is true and `driveTypeArray.type === drive.type`, `drive.ready` should become true.

In array `driveTypeArray` there are two types with `multiAssign: true` and in results it gives me only one drive with `ready:true`

I tried with `forEach` but I think my logic is incorrect.

```js
const driveTypeArray = [{
    type: "HDD",
    multiAssign: false,
    amount: 0,
  },
  {
    type: "SSD",
    multiAssign: true,
    amount: 0,
  },
  {
    type: "EXT",
    multiAssign: false,
    amount: 0,
  },
  {
    type: "NVMe",
    multiAssign: true,
    amount: 0,
  },
]
const drives = [{
    label: "SanDisk SDFJGKHR234234",
    serial: "",
    size: "255 GB",
    type: "SSD",
    ready: false,
    inProgress: false,
    progress: 0
  },
  {
    label: "TOSHIBA HDWD130 - TOSHIBA PRODUCT",
    serial: "",
    size: "2.4 TB",
    type: "HDD",
    ready: false,
    inProgress: false,
    progress: 0
  },
  {
    label: "SanDisk SDFJGKHR234234",
    serial: "",
    size: "255 GB",
    type: "NVMe",
    ready: false,
    inProgress: false,
    progress: 0
  },
  {
    label: "TOSHIBA HDWD130 - TOSHIBA PRODUCT",
    serial: "",
    size: "2.4 TB",
    type: "EXT",
    ready: false,
    inProgress: false,
    progress: 0
  },
]

let driveState = {};

driveTypeArray.map(dType =>
  driveState = {
    drives: drives.map(drive => (drive.type === dType.type ? {
      ...drive,
      ready: true
    } : drive))
  }
)

console.log(driveState)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const driveTypeArray = [{
    type: "HDD",
    multiAssign: false,
    amount: 0,
  },
  {
    type: "SSD",
    multiAssign: true,
    amount: 0,
  },
  {
    type: "EXT",
    multiAssign: false,
    amount: 0,
  },
  {
    type: "NVMe",
    multiAssign: true,
    amount: 0,
  },
]
const drives = [{
    label: "SanDisk SDFJGKHR234234",
    serial: "",
    size: "255 GB",
    type: "SSD",
    ready: false,
    inProgress: false,
    progress: 0
  },
  {
    label: "TOSHIBA HDWD130 - TOSHIBA PRODUCT",
    serial: "",
    size: "2.4 TB",
    type: "HDD",
    ready: false,
    inProgress: false,
    progress: 0
  },
  {
    label: "SanDisk SDFJGKHR234234",
    serial: "",
    size: "255 GB",
    type: "NVMe",
    ready: false,
    inProgress: false,
    progress: 0
  },
  {
    label: "TOSHIBA HDWD130 - TOSHIBA PRODUCT",
    serial: "",
    size: "2.4 TB",
    type: "EXT",
    ready: false,
    inProgress: false,
    progress: 0
  },
]

const updatedDrives = drives.map(drive => {
    const driveType = driveTypeArray.find(driveType => driveType.type === drive.type)
     if(driveType.multiAssign){
        return {...drive, ready: true}
     }
   return drive
})

console.log(updatedDrives)
```

Answer (score 1):

This mutates the `drives` array to set `ready` based on your logic. Is that what you were after?

```js
const driveTypeArray = [{
    type: "HDD",
    multiAssign: false,
    amount: 0,
  },
  {
    type: "SSD",
    multiAssign: true,
    amount: 0,
  },
  {
    type: "EXT",
    multiAssign: false,
    amount: 0,
  },
  {
    type: "NVMe",
    multiAssign: true,
    amount: 0,
  },
]
const drives = [{
    label: "SanDisk SDFJGKHR234234",
    serial: "",
    size: "255 GB",
    type: "SSD",
    ready: false,
    inProgress: false,
    progress: 0
  },
  {
    label: "TOSHIBA HDWD130 - TOSHIBA PRODUCT",
    serial: "",
    size: "2.4 TB",
    type: "HDD",
    ready: false,
    inProgress: false,
    progress: 0
  },
  {
    label: "SanDisk SDFJGKHR234234",
    serial: "",
    size: "255 GB",
    type: "NVMe",
    ready: false,
    inProgress: false,
    progress: 0
  },
  {
    label: "TOSHIBA HDWD130 - TOSHIBA PRODUCT",
    serial: "",
    size: "2.4 TB",
    type: "EXT",
    ready: false,
    inProgress: false,
    progress: 0
  },
]

//If driveTypeArray.multiAssign is true and driveTypeArray.type === drive.type, drive.ready should become true.

//In array driveTypeArray there are two types with multiAssign: true and in results it gives me only one drive with ready:true

let driveState = {};

driveTypeArray.forEach(dType => {
  drives.map(drive => {
    if (dType.multiAssign && drive.type === dType.type)
      drive.ready = true;
    return drive;
  })

})

console.log(drives)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```